# Hibernate Mapping is getting removed but rows from the table are not getting deleted

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate mapping between 2 tables (one to many).

```
    Line.hbm.xml
    /*
    some code
    */
    <list name="schedule" lazy="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan" >
            <key column="line_Id"></key>
            <list-index column="seqNo" base="1" />
            <one-to-many class="com.atc.Schedule" />
    </list>

   Schedule.hbm.xml
    <many-to-one name="line" class="com.atc.Line" lazy="false">
            <meta attribute="use-in-clone">true</meta>
            <column name="line_Id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

When i do `line.getSchedule().clear()`. The mapping between tables is removed. however, the rows are still present in the table. I don't want to use query to delete the rows.

Please help. TIA

Comment: Can you share your code so we can go from there?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `yourRepository.save(yourEntity);` after clearing the data? That should commit the change to the DB.

Comment: i did that as well. but still the rows are not getting deleted

Comment: Can you share an example of the code you are trying to run?